# Transformation $f: \mathbb{F}_2^2 \to \mathbb{F}_2^2$ given by $f(x,y) = (x^2,y^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $f(x,y) =
>  (x^2,y^2)$ linear? Answer the same question if $\mathbb{R}$ is
>   replaced by $\mathbb{F}_2.$

I've proven that it's linear in $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, but in $\mathbb{F}_2$ is it yes because $x = x^2$ and $y=y^2$? So the transformation is not doing anything at all.

Comment: How did you prove $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is linear?

Comment: @Gibbs Oh, I missed to check the second condition (the scalar). It doesn't satisfy that, does it?

Comment: What is $F^2_2$  and how could  $x^2$ be linear in x

Comment: or the first -additive condition

Comment: @Bennett, it is not linear at all. E.g. $f((1,2)+(0,1)) = f((1,3)) = (1,9)$, but $f((1,2))+f((0,1)) = (1,4)+(0,1) = (1,5)$.

Comment: Thanks @Gibbs I forgot that it the square was the normal multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}$, it is not linear as $f((x, y)+(h,0)) = f(x+h, y) = ((x+h)^2, y^2) = (x^2 + h^2 + 2xh, y^2) = (x^2, y^2) + (h^2,0) + (2hx, 0) = f(x, y) + f(h, 0) + (2hx, 0)$.

In $\mathbb{F}_2$, it is just identity map, so yeah it is linear.

Comment: Thanks again. $\color{white}{......................}$

Answer (score 1):

In the case of $\mathbb{F}_2$ the transformation is the identity, because
$$(0,0) \mapsto (0,0),$$
$$(1,0) \mapsto (1,0),$$
$$(0,1) \mapsto (0,1),$$
$$(1,1) \mapsto (1,1),$$
or shortly, as you say, $x=x^2$ and $y=y^2$. So yes, it is linear.

Comment: Thanks. $\color{white}{........................}$

Comment: You are welcome.